# React/Node/Express/Webpack -A valid React element (or null) must be returned

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

link to source code: https://github.com/manster829/MernStackT

I keep getting the error message: Uncaught Error: BugTable.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

I have no idea why, I thought this might have something to do with ES6 or my syntax, but I can't get it. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: further, am I importing the components correctly, is webpack the issue..?

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of silly but you need to move you `(` next to your `return` statement, otherwise you actually return undefined and break out of the function. When you don't have anything next to a return statement javascript assumes you mean to simply return ...

Try this in BugTable.js:

```js
return (
      <div>The list of bugs as a table would come here.</div>
   );
```

Comment: This is correct. I would just add two things 1) `return` by itself on a line returns `undefined`, which is exactly what the error message said. 2) Using eslint as part of your build process can save a lot of time with stuff like this.